# Is it need to covert wgs84 to web mercarto projection?

Tags: python, gis, map-projections

I have a question about projection.  My big gps data is all in wgs84 fomat. Is it need to covert my gps data to web mercarto(epsg3857) befor doing some analysis or visualization, such as determine  points are inside a polygon.     Can I don't do the processing of projection?  I think it will save time  without converting the data.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine to do any approximate calculations using wgs84. But, wgs84 is a geographic coordinate system (uses 3d degrees), not a projected CRS (which use 2d measurements, like meters), so it's not perfect for comparing flat measurements like distances/areas. Your results for things like that could be off.

But, for visualization and just checking whether a point is within a polygon wgs84 should be fine.

Comment: You got it, happy to help :)